# If $p(x)\leq 1$ for $x\in [-1,1]$ find the greatest value of $\int_{-1}^{1}p(x)dx$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

Let p be a polynomial of degree at most 4 such that $p(-1)=p(1)=0$ and $p(0)=1$. If $p(x)\leq 1$ for $x\in [-1,1]$ find the greatest value of $\int_{-1}^{1}p(x)dx$

My Attempt:
Using the given information I was able to obtain a 4 degree polynomial as $f(x)=ax^4+bx^3-(a+1)x^2-bx+1$.

Thus $$\int_{-1}^1p(x)dx=2\int_{0}^{1}\left(ax^4-(a+1)x^2+1\right)dx=\frac{4}{3}-\frac{4a}{15}$$

Answer given is $\frac{8}{5}$.

I have not been able to apply the information that $p(x)\leq 1$ for $x\in [-1,1]$

How to use it

Comment: Is the answer correct? $1-x^2$ works and gives a greater value.

Comment: No. The answer is 8/5. I have edited

Comment: 8/5 occurs when I take the value of a to be -1

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted.

Comment: I have a way..Use that inequality and isolate $a$ in terms of other terms. You will get $ a \geq \frac{1}{x^2-1} +\frac{b}{x} $. Now in the region $(-1,1)$ if you plot the function in terms of $x$ the function will blow up around $0$ if $b$ is non-zero which means $a$ has to be $+\infty$ which is impossible .Thus $b$ has to be zero which then yields $a=-1$...Hope this helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $f(0) = 1$, if $f$ does not exceed $1$ then $0$ must be a local maximum. Therefore $f'(0) = 0$ and $f''(0) \le 0$. This implies $b=0$ and $a \ge -1$. By your calculation, the integral is maximised with $a$ as negative as possible. Therefore $a=-1$.

Comment: The logic is correct, but the integral is wrong in the question. They forgot to multiply by the 2 in the last step (there was a 2 in front of the integral in the previous step). The integral should be $\frac{4(5-a)}{15}$. It is maximized with $a=-1$ and the integral is $\frac{8}5$

Comment: @JohnL Good point, I didn't bother to check the integral!